# Does a custom PHP error handler respect PHP configuration?

Tags: php, error-handling

I'd be glad if someone could explain the architecture of PHP error handling to me. Some specific questions are:

- At what stage does the default error handler read the relevant PHP configuration options?
- Does a custom error handler ignore these options completely?
- How can I make a custom error handler respect the configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty much as you suspect. A custom error handler has to probe for all settings itself and react accordingly.

The [set_error_handler example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) first checks the current active error level, and compares it to the first callback parameter (bitwise and) which denotes the current error type:

```
if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
```

But to initially test if you actually are supposed to print errors, you would need also:

```
ini_get("display_errors") or return;
```

Or to react to more settings and emulate the default error handler, even `ini_get("html_errors")` etc. Unless you do all that manually, your user error handler would display all errors. They are not filtered, the callback receives everything.

---

The PHP default error handler is `php_error_cb` around line 850 here:
http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/main/main.c?revision=309647&view=markup#855

It does a bit more, but also queries the ini registry. That's where `error_reporting` always saves the current state to.

Comment: Thanks! That answers all my questions!