# PHP display_errors = 0 not being respected

Tags: php, warnings, ini-set

I'm using CodeIgniter and I've added the following lines into my index.php:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); 
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/php_errors.log');
```

For some reason, however, PHP is always displaying Warnings/Errors anyway, and not creating a log into the writable directory.  I know the above code is being hit because if I remove the "^ E_NOTICES" part and resubmit, I will see tons of notices.  I also threw a die() statement after the above code to verify it was being hit.  Lastly, I grepped by entire codebase to verify that "display_errors" isn't used later in the code, overwriting my value of 0.

Is there something else I could be missing that prevents me from stopping the display of errors?

Comment: Check your php.ini settings whether your settings are `PHP_INI_USER` or `PHP_INI_ALL`. Otherwise you cannot change them from within your script.

Comment: The documentation says that both arguments to `ini_set` has to be strings, your second argument is an integer. I have no idea if it matters, but you could try putting quotes around the 0.

Comment: @migg I'll bet your on the right track, but I can't find anything like this in my php.ini.  Do you know what specific attribute it is?

Comment: @kba Unfortunately I tried all of the variants.  Appreciate the suggestion, though.

Comment: I actually think this is something specific to CodeIgniter.  Some commenters at http://www.askaboutphp.com/172/codeigniter-handling-errors.html noted the same problem I'm hitting - CodeIgniter ignores php_ini settings.  Not sure how it does that, but apparently it does.  :)

Comment: So without knowing CodeIgniter, I would guess that it changes your settings after you made them?

Comment: @migg Yes, though I thought it would have to do an ini_set.  I grepped the codebase and didn't see it, but as fab points out, it may have been done another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should search for "set_error_handler" in the CodeIgniter source. It looks like their error handler respects the `error_reporting` setting but not the `display_errors` setting, a common mistake. See also: [Does a custom PHP error handler respect PHP configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699930/does-a-custom-php-error-handler-respect-php-configuration/5700117#5700117)